# Searching a pattern in file names with number

Tags: bash, zsh, wildcards, date

I have a large number of files in a folder each with the date as the filename.
For example

```
20130101
20130102
20130103
.
.
.
20130131
```

similarly for other months 20130201 to 20130230, the pattern is [Year][Month][Day]. 
I need to make a tar file of the first fifteen files from JAN to APRIL 
(i.e `2013[01-04][01-15]`), since double digit number range is not allowed in `grep`. How should I search this pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
tar zcf ~/file.tar.gz 20130<1-4><1-15>
```

If you have to use `bash`:

```
shopt -s extglob
tar zcf ~/file.tar.gz 20130[1-4]@(0?|1[0-5])
```

Answer (score 3):

Use find to find the filenames:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "20130[1-4]0?" -o -name "20130[1-4]1[0-5]"
```

check if that is the correct set, and use the output as input for `cpio`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "20130[1-4]0?" -o -name "20130[1-4]1[0-5]" | cpio --create --format=ustar -O file.tar
```

@richard pointed out this could traverse in sub-directories (if a sub-directory matches the pattern) (and that shell expanded the pattern, corrected).

Expanding on the commandline runs the *risk* of the commandline becoming too long, which might happen if you had a file every few seconds for every day (`20130101-00005`, `20130101-00007`. Piping the filename into `cpio` does not have  problem.

Comment: Note it is not find that is doing the work here, but the shell. Warning will recurse directories, use echo instead of find to not do this.

Comment: would'nt the space after question mark give an error?

Comment: @Aditya why? it needs the space.

Comment: @richard Sorry! my mistake just looked at an example of it

Comment: Maybe call these first in your script `shopt -s nullglob; shopt -u failglob`, to stop it failing when a file is not found.

Comment: @richard, You right about the shell doing the work, but not about the recursion in directories *and displaying* unless there are folders with that filename pattern. That is different when you use `find . -name "somepattern"`

Comment: Yes that is what I meant only recurses directories that match the pattern, not all directories.

Answer (score 2):

The grep bit is.

```
grep -zE "^20130[1-4](0[1-9]|1[0-5])$"
```

Comment: std `grep` will work as well. Since this particular pattern happens to want months 01-04, the first 0 can be included with the year. So, `grep  '20130[1-4][01..15]'` will match the specified range.

Comment: @bdowning, no, `[01..15]`, same as `[015.]` matches any of those 4 characters `0`, `1`, `.`, or `5`.

Answer (score 0):

You can `tar czvf file.tar.gz $(ls | grep "201301\|201302\|201303\|201304" | grep -v "16\|17\|18\|19\|20\|21\|22\|23\|24\|25\|26\|27\|28\|29\|30\|31")` from the base directory.

Comment: Beware though this should work it is fragile: e.g. if the year was 2016 it would not work.